# How to add "if" statements such that certain related ones are grouped together

Tags: python

```
 random1 = ["\nHello"]
 random2 = ["\nHi"]


    message = random.choice(random1 + random2)
    print(message)

if message in random2:
    question = input("\ny/n ==> ")

elif message in random1:
    print("blue")

if (question == "y"):
    print("blue blue blue")
```

From the code above, how do I group "if (question == "y")"  with "if message in random2: question = input("\ny/n ==> ")"

In other words, since both these statements are related, how can I group these two if statements together such that it does not confuse the program when writing another if statement for  "if (question == "y")" as shown in the code above.

Note: I can't just combine the if statements as "if x = a and y = b" because I want "if (question == "y")" to come after "message in random2:
    question = input("\ny/n ==> ")", not both occuring at the same time.

Comment: Why should they not occur at the same time? And you can nest the second if statement within the first by indenting it one level.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this is what you want to do :-

Just nest the if statement in the right place

```
import random
random1 = ["\nHello"]
random2 = ["\nHi"]


message = random.choice(random1 + random2)
print(message)

if message in random2:
    question = input("\ny/n ==> ")
    if (question == "y"):
        print("blue blue blue")

elif message in random1:
    print("blue")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missed what you want but if you want the two statements behind each other wouldn't this do the trick?

```
random1 = ["\nHello"]
random2 = ["\nHi"]


    message = random.choice(random1 + random2)
    print(message)

if message in random2:
    question = input("\ny/n ==> ")
    if (question == "y"):
        print("blue blue blue")

elif message in random1:
    print("blue")
```

Answer (score 0):

Python uses white-space and text-formatting to determine the interpretation of the code.

You must indent your IF statements in a nested structure to achieve what you want.

```
if message in random2:
    question = input("\ny/n ==> ")
    if (question == "y"):
        print("blue blue blue")
elif message in random1:
    print("blue")
```

Above will run the "if message in random2" if True then it will ask for input and check if this input is yes. None of this happens if "if message in random2" is false, it will instead move on to "elif message in random1:".

I believe this is what you were looking for.